# Safe Calls in Kotlin with Array is confuse

Tags: arrays, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

There is an array: `notes: Array<KeyValueNote>?` and I use the Kotlin `1.0.5-2` in the following code.

#### I want

```
if (notes != null) {
    for (note in notes) {
        // Put the note to the payload Json object only if the note is non-null.
        payloadJson.put(note.key, note.value)
    }
}
```

#### But there are several alternations

```
    // Alternative 1.
    notes?.let {
        it.takeWhile { it != null /** Inspection will note The condition 'it != null' is always true' in here**/ }.forEach { payloadJson.put(it.key, it.value) }
    }

    // Alternative 2.
    notes?.takeWhile { it != null /** Inspection will note The condition 'it != null' is always true' in here**/ }?.forEach { payloadJson.put(it.key, it.value) }

    // Alternative 3.
    notes?.filterNotNull()?.forEach { payloadJson.put(it.key, it.value) }
```

### My Question

1. You can see there is Inspection Note `The condition 'it != null' is always true` in the Alternative 1&2, **whether the inspection is right?** because I want to ensure only the non-null item in the `notes` can be put to the `payloadJson`.
2. In Alternative 3, you can see there is a Safe Call in `filterNotNull()?.`, **whether the `?` is needed in here?**, because I review the source code, the result of the `filterNotNull()` can't be null, but when I remove `?` in there, the compile is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `notes` is `Array<KeyValueNote>?`, which means that the elements of the array **can not be null**, but the array itself can. Thus, your code in the "I want" section is correct. A shorter alternative for it would be:

```
notes?.forEach { payloadJson.put(it.key, it.value) }
```

About your alternatives:

- Alternative 1: Never use `let` like this. It should be a safe call `?.` (like in Alternative 2), nothing else. My heart bleeds when I see `let` in those situations :(
- Alternative 2: `takeWhile` and `filter` are obviously not the same thing. I guess you wanted `filterNotNull`, like in the Alternative 3
- Alternative 3: Since the elements of the array can NOT be null (because of their type), `filterNotNull` is equivalent to `toList` since it just copies the content

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it now.

Comment: But I'm confused  when I provide a `notes` with some `null` elements to the method with the `Array<KeyValueNote>?` parameter, how Kotlin handle this case, crash? or remove all `null` elements automatically?

Comment: For one thing, you wont be able to do this inside Kotlin itself because of the types. You'll need to construct that array in Java and pass it to the method. Then Kotlin will crash at the first moment a `null` is extracted from the array.

Answer (score 2):

Inspection is right. You declare your notes variable to be nullable array of not nullable items.

```
notes: Array<KeyValueNote>? // Can be null, cannot contain nulls.
notes: Array<KeyValueNote?> // Cannot be null, can contain nulls.
```

With this in mind, **filterNotNull()?.** is necessary for this array because it is nullable. You can find more information on Kotlin null safety in [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're confused by `it` parameter used in different scopes. The first alternative can be rewritten as:

```
notes?.let { notesSafe:Array<KeyValueNote> -> // notesSafe is not null here
    notesSafe
      .takeWhile { item:KeyValueNote -> item != null } // item is already not null by it's type definition
      .forEach { payloadJson.put(it.key, it.value) }
}
```

The second alternative is pretty much the same and the compiler note about `item:KeyValueNote` is true for the same reason: `val items:Array<KeyValueNote>?` cannot hold `null` values - but the `items` itself could be `null`.

The 3rd alternative has a safe call to `filterNotNull` which returns source collection with `null` values removed. However as mentioned `Array<KeyValueNote>` cannot have `null` values in it hence the `filterNotNull` is not required.

In conclusion the expression can be written as:

```
notes?.forEach { payloadJson.put(it.key, it.value) }
```